# Hats on iOS app?

Tags: support, ios-app, winter-bash-2014

Is there a button to access the Hatz on WB14 on the mobile app (especially iOS) and let me view the Hatz I have earned so far? Or is it only accessible with the website version?

Answer (score 2):

No, only in the full website (neither apps, nor mobile web have this functionality). The Hatz are accessible(viewable and changeable).

Comment: Should be have, not don't have. Thanks, by the way.

Comment: @Arc I suggest you to hire as developer and implement hatz in the apps! :)

Comment: :) I'd love to. When I turn 18.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 I don't think there's age restriction for working as programmer.

Comment: @Sha There is a small restriction: 0-99 ("Only people with positive age up to 99 years"). I tried, but was to old to apply for this job unfortunately.

Comment: @ShadowWizard But I'm not very experienced. I think 18 is a good age to start working, but not 13.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 experience isn't always required. [Example 1](http://uk.businessinsider.com/shubham-banerjee-braigo-labs-2014-11), [Example 2](http://tech.co/13-year-old-ceo-makes-deal-shark-tank-2014-10). ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Amazing... Thanks. Choice's mine though ;)

Answer (score 1):

The Winterbash is a temporary Javascript-driven add-on for the site. The mobile apps do not support such temporary extras, so you won't see the hats in the apps.

You *do* get some hats for using the mobile apps, however! This very dashing beret-like thing is awarded for using the iOS app, for example:

[image: ninja with apple hat]

The mobile specific hats are:

- [*On the road*](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/on-the-road) - Post a question using the mobile app.
- [*Bugdroid*](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/bugdroid) - Post, vote, edit or comment using the Android app.
- [*Not a cherry*](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/not-a-cherry) - Post, vote, edit or comment using the iOS app.
- [*Got a tablet for Christmas*](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/got-a-tablet-for-christmas) - Post on Christmas day using the mobile app. Presumably it doesn't *have* to be brand new. :-)

<sup><sub>*Reposted from [Winterbash hats in Android app?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280289/winter-bash-hats-in-android-application/280290#280290)*</sub></sup>