# Please implement hats in the mobile StackExchange App

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, profile-picture, winter-bash-2014, mobile-app

I am aware of [Hats on iOS app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245392/hats-on-ios-app) .
This is a feature request to the developers to add hats to the app.

I know everyone would love the ability to see those amazing pieces of apparel, and I'm wondering if they are coming to iOS and Android apps. Why should / shouldn't hats be implemented on the mobile app?

[image: My profile as shown on my iPad.]

As you can see, it's a very boring profile picture I have without a hat.

I am not asking "Why aren't hats supported?" but instead I am asking this as a `feature-request`, one that I hope will make it to the mobile app, and one that I believe that most users would enjoy.

Comment: +1 to [the feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/245678/3)

Comment: Winterbash is very *temporary*. Reimplementing the feature in the mobile apps is a huge amount of work and there are other, more pressing features to implement here (reviewing and chat for example) that would have impact the year round.