# Why should I have to download an app to get the BugDroid hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

I'm viewing the site on my Android tablet, but I don't get any hat for that because I am using a Web browser. Why is the hat only awarded to those who succumb to the pressure to be treated as second class citizens and [not get all the features of the Web site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245392/hats-on-ios-app)?

Comment: If your god intended for you to view things through a browser, why did he take so long getting it made?

Comment: @random he hates me

Comment: Stop taking her name in vain then

Comment: @random don't think i ever mentioned her name...

Comment: It also means not proclaiming what the flying spaghetti monster would have done or wanted

Comment: Why should you do anything just for a hat that will vanish soon?

Comment: Because, eh, conditions require this...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

... and on the sixth day, he created Chrome? I think you're giving browsers a bit too much credit :)

The hat exists to provide incentive for folks with compatible devices to *try the app*. You don't have to keep it if you don't want it, heck, you hardly have to use it. A lot of work has gone into giving people an experience that *doesn't suck* while using it, an improvement over the current mobile interface.

The same goes for the IOS related hat, it's just there to give you another reason to try something (if you needed a reason, and found that to be a good enough reason to do it).

If you don't want to use the app, don't use the app. If you want the hat, you have to try the app - because we've already *got* plenty of feedback from folks that were using a browser on said device - *they really wanted an app instead*.